# What are vehicle emission limitations in Bavaria?

Tags: ford, emissions, mustang

I currently work in USA but I'm going to relocate to Münich, Bavaria. 
The thing is I want to transport my 2001 Ford Mustang to Germany. My only concern (other than costs of course) is that European ecological standards are stricter.

I've tried to Google what are current emission standards and here's what I've found:

Foreign vehicles emissions are taken primarily by vehicle age, as in [this table](http://www.urbanaccessregulations.eu/de-foreign-table)

From that table as far as I understand, it is considered to be Euro 3 - but it looks like that for diesel, so I'm confused. Also, I'm not sure I understand what does Euro 3 mean in context of driving in Münich specifically.

So, in short: is it allowed to drive 2001 Ford Mustang in Münich?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it involves regional laws and regulations that are subject to change and not applicable to motor vehicle maintenance and repair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, this doesn't apply to Bavaria alone, but to all Germany.

You are right, diesel and petrol cars get the same stickers, though, petrol cars get either no sticker (no catalytic converter, EURO 1) or a green sticker (with converter, EURO2 or better). So this stickers mainly affect diesel cars.

In general, the class of a car is usually determined by their EU emission standard, or, if not available, by their date of initial registration.

Anyhow, you will get the green sticker.

About driving:

Today, according to [this site](http://gis.uba.de/website/umweltzonen/umweltzonen.php) several cities have environmental zones ("Umweltzone") where only cars with a green sticker are allowed. Neu-Ulm seems to be the only exception and allows yellow stickers, too.
And the Autobahn is exempt from the zones, i.e. you can drive any car over the autobahn through a zone.

The zones are marked with such signs (which in this case allows cars with red, yellow and green stickers to pass):
[image]

On the site linked above, you can also get a map of Munich, indicating the zone. (Though, it's low resolution. Searching more, the street "Mittlerer Ring / B2R" is the border of the zone)

However, since your car will get a green sticker, don't worry.

May be one additional hint: The cost for the sticker varies a lot, the TÜV is quite expensive (up to 20€). There are online shops selling them for 5-6€, local shops like A.T.U. will also be cheaper. I don't know how much they take for a foreign car, but since you need the sticker only inside the zones you may have time to get a sticker when you are in Germany.

Answer (score 3):

Look again at the page you referred to, you need the second table marked 'Petrol'.

According to [this page](http://www.tuev-sued.de/auto_fahrzeuge/feinstaub-plakette/feinstaubplakette_ausland/england) by the German certification authority TUV, you are allowed to drive your Mustang in the Münich city center.

All petrol cars that conform to EUR I and higher (From 1 Jan. 1993) get a green Umwelt-sticker and are allowed to drive everywhere.

So all you need to do is get a green sticker ([order form](https://www.tuev-sued.de/auto_fahrzeuge/feinstaub-plakette/bestellen/england)), apply it to your car and you're done.